# C# How to make synchronous method waiting for events to fire?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events, controls

I have custom browser class which is capable of firing a lot of events depending on browsed page state. Now I need to perform some operations on this web page using my browser, but they have to run sequentialy, each operation needs data from the previous one.
The cleanest way to achieve this is to make a synchronous methods waiting for browser to do its job. I made it like this:

```
public incomplete class MyClass {
    // (...) lots of stuff comes here, it's a web browser :)
    public bool MySyncMethod(object data) {
        bool success = false;
        bool wait = true;
        MyEventHandler = new EventHandler((o, e) => {
            data = MyEventProvidedData; // belive me, it's threre when it fired
            success = true; // let's assume it always succeed
            wait = false; // now we can move on to the rest of our long chain
        });
        // (...) here I have some more event handlers which can end my method...
        MyAsyncMethod(data); // so it started and will fire MyEventHandler soon
        while (wait) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        return success;
   }
}
```

But something seems wrong here. If I used threads, I'd just place myThread.Join() instead of my while loop and it would wait for my thread to complete. Is it something similar to Thread.Join() which can be used with events fired by controls? Is there something to use instead of while loop? Is it a cleaner way to achieve my goal? The code above works in the real app, but I think it's not optimal.

And there is a good reason I don't use threads here - all communication between threads and ActiveX control must be thread-safe, and this is not trivial to achieve. Yes, I tried :) This code was a hell to debug, so I decided to rewrite it.

Comment: Did you take a look to the example code of Monitor.Pulse? Here on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try use ManualResetEvent:

```
    var wait = new ManualResetEvent(false); 
    var handler = new EventHandler((o, e) => wait.Set()); 
    MyAsyncMethod(data, handler); // so it started and will fire handler soon 
    wait.WaitOne();
```

Comment: This also works for Action events with multiple types, so EventHandler above can be substituted with Action<object,int,string,int> or whatever your Action looks like.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to use tasks, you could use the [WaitAll Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx)

But you say you can't use threads. Still the asyncmethod must start some kind of threading so there must be some threading involved?
If the problem is that the asyncmethod must post back to the original thread for the active x control to work, you can use the ASyncOperationManager ( shameless own blog post link: http://blog.subrosoftware.nl/?p=42 ), or the [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperationmanager.aspx) Could that perhaps solve the thread callback issue?

Comment: Yes, you're right - I have to use threads, but I can limit cross-thread calls to necessary minimum. I don't have to access ActiveX directly, but I need to access WebBrowser component based on ActiveX. It could be done thread-safe using Invoke. So most of the code using browser will be done in form class containing the browser - within its thread. Only starting task and receiving data would require Invokes so it would be pretty simple.